# Eclipse: How do you configure the perspectives listed on the menu when you click "Open Perspective"?

Tags: eclipse

I'm constantly switching between PyDev and Debug perspectives in Eclipse. But when I click on the "Open Perspective" icon in the upper right corner, I get "Java, Jave Browsing, XML | Other..." Sure, clicking Other... will get me to PyDev, but how can I just get Java, Java Browsing and XML off the menu and put PyDev and Debug on it? (And, yeah, the double-arrow selector to show perspectives is there, and it shows Java no matter what perspectives were recently used. And I've even set PyDev as my default perspective.)

Thanks a ton for any pointers anyone can give!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have both perspectives opened for the first time they should be in the list of perspectives to the upper right so you shouldn't need to use that menu anymore. You could switch with the buttons or the keyboard shortcut (`Ctrl-F8` is default) between the perspectives in the list.

To customize the list: Menu `Window > Customize Perspective`, Tab `Shortcuts`, Dropdown `Submenus: Open Perspective`.

Comment: "To customize the list: Menu Window > Customize Perspective, Tab Shortcuts, Dropdown Submenus: Open Perspective" FTW!! Many thanks. Never would have found that on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcuts to the rescue!

```
Ctrl + Shift + F8 - This will take you to the previous perspective
Ctrl + f8 - This will take you to the next perspective
```